# How to bind a NSTextField to a raw string while displaying another attributed string?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, editing, nstextfield

I'm using view-based `NSTableView` and would like to allow users to edit text in place. Cocoa typically has superb support for this, but I am not sure how to bind the value of `NSTextField` to one string while displaying a slightly different string to the user, as shown below. For example, when user clicks on a text field or presses enter key to edit, the field editor should only be filled with `exportTest.zip` and not `exportTest.zip Shared`, and whatever edit user makes should only affect the `exportTest.zip` value as well. Can this be done using cocoa text?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done with NSFormatter however just in case anyone else struggles as I did I thought I'd point out that in order to display a different string when editing you will need to override `editingStringForObjectValue:`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use an `NSFormatter`? You could formulate the string *Shared* similar as you would do with a currency symbol. Your model simple stores the file name and *Shared* is part of the format.

Comment: I've tried using NSFormatter but then the field editor gets filled with the formatted string (eg exportTest.zip Shared) rather than the raw value.