# Can you display one (attributed) string in a NSTextField, but use a different one for editing?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I have a CoreData object, and I want to display information from that object in a `NSTextField`.

The object has two relevant properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *text;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSAttributedString *displayText;
```

I would like to display the latter in the text field, but allow the user to edit the former.  (The latter string is a simple transformation of the former, with some characters removed and with some attributes applied.)

How can I achieve this?

---

There are two more points worth noting:

- the `NSTextField` is inside a `NSOutlineView`, which means that the delegate methods `control:textShould{Begin,End}Editing:` are not called correctly: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121352/nstextfield-not-calling-delegate-when-inside-an-nstablecellview).  This means that I can't manually set the `.attributedStringValue` of the field before and after editing.
- As my object is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, I cannot use it alongside a `NSFormatter` via `setObjectValue:` (as it does not implement `<NSCopying>`). I thus can't seem to make the approach [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426255/how-to-bind-a-nstextfield-to-a-raw-string-while-displaying-another-attributed-st) work.

---

I'm open to either using an `NSFormatter` subclass, or (preferably) finding a way to bind the text displayed normally and while editing to the properties directly.

My outline view is view-based, so if there's a better fit for the job than `NSTextField` I am happy to use it instead.

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? I've got the same question. I'd like my NSTextField to display a different value but edit a slightly modified string